# How to kill intent Service

Tags: jakarta-mail, commonsware-cwac, android-intentservice

I am using wakefull intent service and works very fine. But currently i see that many times my intent service is in wait satate.I found that problem is with javamail as it goes in deadlock state when ever internet connection is resets.

I search option to intrupt operation java mail but can't find any solution.I have set IMAP,SMTP Time out property but it is not working.

```
                 if(msg1[0]!= null)
         {
             if(!Mail.store.isConnected() || f== null)
             {
                 Log.v(tag, "StoreNot Connected");
                 m = new Mail(username, password);
                 f =m.getlable("Message_"+nick);    
                 Log.v(tag, "Store Connected");

             }
             try{
                 Log.v(tag, "Sending Mail");    
                 //Get DeadLock Hear
                 f.appendMessages(msg1);     

                 sucess_flag=1;
                 Log.v(tag, "Mail Send");
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                e.printStackTrace(); 

             }catch(Throwable e)
             {
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
             }

         }
```

So now i am looking for an option to restart or kill the current intent service.

Is there any option for this?

If not then is it a good idea to create theads from intentservice and kill them instead?

Comment: How exactly have you set the timeouts and what JavaMail protocols are you using?

Comment: using this code :
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", 60000); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.timeout", 60000); 
    props.put("mail.imap.connectiontimeout", 60000); 
    props.put("mail.imap.timeout", 60000); 
    props.put("mail.imap.writetimeout", 60000);

Comment: Are you using the "smtp" and "imap" protocols, or the "smtps" and "imaps" protocols? Also, older versions of JavaMail didn't support properties set as numbers, only properties set as Strings.  What version of JavaMail are you using?

Comment: you are right i should have tried IMAPS as i am using gmail for test server and it uses secure connection.

Comment: i am using libs from this project http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list

Comment: Get rid of mail.jar from that project and get a newer version from the [JavaMail project page](http://javamail.java.net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
Intent GPSService = new Intent(context, TrackGPS.class);
context.stopService(GPSService);
```

Comment: Does it not wait till work in onHandleIntent fuction complite?

Comment: Hi it works but only problem is i can see old threads in DDMS.e.g. Two Threads with same intent.
 is it natural?